# Why doesn't out-of-scope variables still work in python?

Tags: python

```
for i in range(10):
    s = 'a'
    print(i)
print(s)
```

It prints out 'a' although s is out of scope. This makes programming more difficult for such cases because when you are referencing 's' outside of the for loop, you assume that 's' is defined outside of the loop.

Is this normal in Python?

Comment: `Is this normal in Python?` There are thousands of posts/articles/sites that detail how Python scope works, and with examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, I quote shamelessly [from this page](https://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html)

> A variable which is defined in the main body of a file is called a global variable. It will be visible throughout the file, and also inside any file which imports that file.

```py
# This is a global variable
a = 0

if a == 0:
    # This is still a global variable
    b = 1

def my_function(c):
    # this is a local variable
    d = 3
    print(c)
    print(d)

# Now we call the function, passing the value 7 as the first and only parameter
my_function(7)

# a and b still exist
print(a)
print(b)

# c and d don't exist anymore -- these statements will give us name errors!
print(c)
print(d)
```

Update: to prevent global variables, among others, you can use a main block:

```py
def my_function(c):
    # this is a local variable
    d = 3
    print(c)
    print(d)


def main():
    # This is a local variable now
    a = 0

    if a == 0:
        b = 1
    # Now we call the function, passing the value 7 as the first and only parameter
    my_function(7)

    # a and b still exist
    print(a)
    print(b)

    # c and d don't exist any more 
    print(c)
    print(d)
   

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    # a and b don't exist
    print(a)
    print(b)

    # c and d don't exist
    print(c)
    print(d)
```

Comment: Btw, just because I stumbled over it again - I (and I believe many python devs) wrap the main code in a main function

Answer (score 2):

This is normal in Python. If your `for`-loop had been inside a function, `s` would have been inside the function's scope; however, since it is not, everything inside the `for`-loop is in the main scope.

If you do not wish `s` to be defined in the main scope, the easiest way would be to encapsulate the `for`-loop in a function:

```
def print_to_ten():
    for i in range(10):
        s = 'a'
        print(i)

print_to_ten()
print(s)
```

`print(s)` now returns the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 's' is not defined
```

Comment: Is this a good design or bad compared with other languages? Or it's a compromise for some other benefits?

Comment: @marlon Good or bad for what purpose? Languages have different niches and idioms. The developers of Python designed its scopes to be helpful and intuitive for the intended uses of Python. It certainly works; it's not hard to write functions. (If you don't like writing functions, you probably won't like Python.)

Comment: Even in function, you will still have the same issue, because for loop is just a little part of a function probably, and you may intentionally or accidentally refer to a variable defined in a local scope even though it's defined in a function and the caller is also inside a function.  .

Comment: @marlon It is possible that you could accidentally refer to a variable defined in the same scope. But naming variables more descriptively and keeping functions small, both good practices anyway, mitigate this possibility. Besides, you can still move the `for`-loop to a new function, either within the original function or outside it.

Answer (score 0):

It is normal in for-loops. Instead in for loops used in comprehensions, the scope is local and the variables defined are not accessible outside of the comprehension.